# How do I delete just the Time Machine files on my Drobo external filesystem?

Tags: macos, time-machine, drobo

I have a folder on my Drobo called "HFS+ Private Directory Data" and it contains old Time Machine data. I cannot delete it and do not want to reformat my drobo. I have tried 'option' trashing and various Terminal hacks but to no avail. I am using Lion now.

It's about 36 GB and I would love this space back. I'm running Lion on a 2006 MacPro and it's a four bay Drobo with 3 TB of 4 TB used. I use the Drobo for image files and a separate drive for Time Machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Is your "separate drive for Time Machine" a statement of your new setup intentions or part of the problem? Also, drobo have several products and software that behave differently - you might want to list the specifics if you don't want a general answer. (I.e. Delete using time machine interface and contact drobo if that fails)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you delete it from the Time Machine interface?  Or is this a backup from a computer you no longer use?  If the latter then there shouldn't be much/any risk in just force deleting it.  If I remember right then you need to clear the immutable flag from the directory (or from all the files?)

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't try to delete it by hand.  See the Hard Links section of: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html

It contains info about hard links on your filesystem which are key to how Time Machine works.  The directory should be hidden by default.